# How to prove propositional logic formulas with axioms using modus Ponens?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, axioms

I have a problem understanding how modus ponens work when trying to deduce proof using already made axioms to formulas we want to prove that it is valid.
This is the list of axioms:

```
 α→β→α
    (α→β→γ)→(α→β)→α→γ
    α→β→(α∧β)
    (α∧β)→α
    (α∧β)→β
    α→(α∨β)
    β→(α∨β)
    (α→γ)→(β→γ)→(α∨β)→γ
    (α→β)→(α→¬β)→¬α
    ¬¬α→α
    ⊥→α
    α→⊤
```

[https://members.loria.fr/pdeGroote/logic/logic13.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiihw.png)

the link in the very end of the page shows a formula proved using axioms with modus ponens but I did not understand how they go from a step to another step. I know that modes is just inference rule but the shift from premise to conclusion is totally ambiguous.
for example: how would we decide whether this formula is valid or not using the axioms with modus ponens. I know we can use truth tables. But this one got me truly perplexed.

```
((A → B) → A) → A
```

Comment: Some more parentheses may help...

Comment: Top left is $a \to ((b \to a) \to a)$ and has the "logical form": $\alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$. Thus, it is an instance of Ax.1

Comment: Same for top right: $[a \to ((b \to a) \to a)] \to [(a \to (b \to a)) \to (a \to a)]$ whose logical form is $(α→(β→γ))→((α→β)→(α→γ))$, and thus it is an instance of Ax.2

Comment: To them you can apply Modus Ponens to get the formula: $(a→(b→a))→(a→a)$. Now we have the next step: the left formula is $a \to (b \to a)$ i.e. Ax.1 again; using MP with the right formula you derive the conclusion (bottom formula): $a \to a$.